# Passing parentheses as script argument to macOs defaults command

Tags: bash, macos, quoting

I'm writing out a setup script for my dotFiles.  Part of this script will get some basic contact info to display on the lock screen in case my laptop is found.  At this stage, the message looks like this

"If found, please call 000-000-0000 or email my@email.com"

Here's the function I've written to do this:

```bash
function collectInfo() {
    echo "We'll set a lock screen message for anyone who finds your laptop."
    echo "Please enter a valid phone number: "
    read phonenumber
    echo "Please enter a valid email: "
    read contactemail
    msg="If found, please call "$phonenumber" or email "$contactemail
    sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow LoginwindowText $msg
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Data entered"
        defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow LoginwindowText
    else
        echo "There was an issue with your input.  Please try again"
        collectInfo
    fi
}
```

I hit a snag if I try to pass parentheses to the loginwindow setting, for instance (000) 000-0000.  I can echo out $msg and it seems to be creating the string just fine.  Is there some way to pass a string with parentheses as an argument, or will I have to use sed to knock them out?

Comment: Aside: Don't end the quotes before your expansions. That is to say, your line assigning `msg` should be `msg="If found, please call $phonenumber or email $contactemail"`, with the parameter expansions **inside** the quotes. (This is a class of bugs that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch).

Comment: Also, in general, don't use `$?` if you don't have to. You could just write `if sudo defaults write ...; then echo "Data entered"; else echo "There was an issue"; fi`, with no test of `$?` at all.

Comment: And quote `$msg` -- it needs to be `"$msg"`. That may be the only thing you need to fix to resolve your bug, though it's hard to say without your question including the exact error. Without those quotes, each word of your message is passed to the `defaults` command as a separate argument; if `defaults` handles arguments that start and end with parenthesis unusually, well, there's our problem.

Comment: See [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls), particularly entry #14. And run your code through http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: (As another aside -- the `function` keyword is best avoided, as it makes your code incompatible with baseline implementations of `/bin/sh` without adding any benefit over the POSIX-standardized function declaration syntax, which is just `collectInfo() {` -- meaning you can just leave out `function` entirely).

Comment: That is a whole lot of super helpful info.  Thanks, @CharlesDuffy!  I made some changes, ran the script through shellcheck.net (which reports no errors now), and I'm getting an error `defaults[20855:3459827] Could not parse: If found, please call (000) 000-0000 or email test@email.com.  Try single-quoting it.`.  Seems like it's `defaults` that's the problem then, huh?

Comment: Yup, need to look up what kind of string format it expects. As a WAG, might try `"'${msg}'"`, injecting literal single quotes inside the syntactic double quotes -- or `"\"${msg}\""`, for literal double quotes inside the syntactic ones. (The curly braces aren't strictly necessary in either of those cases, btw; just a stylistic/readability call on whether to include them).

Comment: `"'${msg}'"` did the trick.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: I'll add an answer to that effect, then, unless you want to do so yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two confounding factors here:

- Failing to put quotes around `$msg` splits it into a number of separate arguments.
- An argument that starts with `(` and ends with `)` is parsed by `defaults` as an array, so `(000)` was parsed as an array with one element.

To ensure that your content is parsed as a string, you can begin and end it with literal quotes:

```
defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow LoginwindowText "'$msg'"
```

The outer double quotes (`"`) are processed by the shell to ensure that the entire message is passed as just one argument; the inner single quotes (`'`) are passed to `defaults` and guide how it parses the value.